# Permutations with inequalities constraint - analytical solution

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, permutations

I asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273978/permutations-with-inequalities-constraint) in how many ways could I arrange the first $6$ positive integers such that this inequalities chain will hold

$a < b > c < d < e > f$

The answer showed me how to use Mathematica to count  those permutations.

Now I would like to know how can I derive that answer analytically. In the case above I have $5$ inequality signs, so I can have $2^5 = 32$ different inequalities chains, and each one correspond to one of those numbers of permutations

$\{1, 5, 10, 14, 19, 26, 35, 40, 61\}$

Of course if I sum all the permutations I have a total of $6!= 720$, but I don't know how to calculate each one for a specific inequalities chain.

Edit: the answers resolve the case with alternating $<,>$ signs, but what if they in a specific, non alternating, chain?

Comment: It's not alternating,, there's $c<d<e$. I could find this from OEIS: http://oeis.org/A229551 of which this is a case $n=6$.

Comment: Let consider this specific chain. e is at least 4 because it is greater than c, d and f. If e=4, then  a=5, b=6, c,d,f are 1,2,3. f can be any of 3, then c,d are determined as unique; 3 permutations. If e=5, then b=6, a,c,d,f are 1,2,3,4. a and f can be any of 4, then c,d are determined as unique; ${4\choose 3}=6$ permutations. If e=6, then f can be any of 5 remaining. Let WLOG f=5. Then b can be 3 or 4. If b=3 then d=4, a.c are 1,2; 5 × 2 permutations. If b=4, then a,c,d are 1,2,3. a can be any of 3 then c,d are determined as unique; 5 × 3 permutations. Totally 3+6+10+15=34 permutations.

Comment: Let consider this specific chain. e is at least 4 because it is greater than c, d and f. If e=4, then  a=5, b=6, c,d,f are 1,2,3. f can be any of 3, then c,d are determined as unique; 3 permutations. If e=5, then b=6, a,c,d,f are 1,2,3,4. a and f can be any of 4, then c,d are determined as unique; $4\cdot 3=12$ permutations. If e=6, then f can be any of 5 remaining. Let WLOG f=5. Then b can be 3 or 4. If b=3 then d=4, a.c are 1,2; 5 × 2 permutations. If b=4, then a,c,d are 1,2,3. a can be any of 3 then c,d are determined as unique; 5 × 3 permutations. Totally 3+12+10+15=40 permutations.

Comment: I suppose, definition of alternating signs requires 1< 1> 1< 1> and so on, then it's not alternating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for prematurely closing your question as a duplicate. Although counting the things you want – linear extensions – for general posets is indeed hard, the special case of chained inequalities can be solved in polynomial time as detailed below.

Given the poset $x_1-x_2-\cdots-x_n$ where $-$ is $<$ or $>$, find all maximal elements. These are the only places the largest number can go. For each "peak":

- Delete the peak, splitting the chain into two sub-chains of lengths $k$ on the left and $n-k-1$ on the right (see picture)
- Recurse into the sub-chains and count their numbers of linear extensions – say the left and right chains have $L$ and $R$ of them
- The number of linear extensions of the whole chain with the largest number at that peak is $LR\binom{n-1}k$

[image]

Then the final answer is the sum of these counts for each peak. Because only the $O(n^2)$ continuous sub-chains are considered, memoising their extension counts leads to an $O(n^3)$ time algorithm.

---

For the given inequality chain $a<b>c<d<e>f$ applying the above procedure yields this evaluation tree, where $(x)$ denotes the number of linear extensions of chain $x$:

- `(a<b>c<d<e>f) = (a)(c<d<e>f) + (a<b>c<d)(f) = 1×3×5 + 5×1×5 = 40`

  - `(c<d<e>f) = (c<d)(f) = 1×1×3 = 3`
  - `(a<b>c<d) = (a)(c<d) + (a<b>c)() = 1×1×3 + 2×1×1 = 5`

    - `(a<b>c) = (a)(c) = 1×1×2 = 2`

The base cases used here are total orders, which have only one linear extension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If possible could you just make an example with the same inequality chain I talked about?

Comment: @user967210 Done.